# How to get the support fragment manager object in fragment without create static field in activity

Tags: android, android-fragments

Hello I want to call `getSupportFragmentManager` in a static fragment but it is giving me error.

> Non static method getSupportFragmentManager can not be referenced in static class.

```
public static class DemoFragment extends Fragment {

    public DemoFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment, container, false);

        return rootView;
    }

    @OnClick(R.id.button)
    public void clickButton() {
        DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment(new DatePickerListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {

            }
        });
        newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker"); // HERE ERROR
    }
}
```

To solve this I created a static variable in activity like

```
private static FragmentManager fragmentManager;
```

and assigned it `onCreate` like

```
fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Please help how to get the support fragment manager object in fragment without create static field in activity or is this correct way which I did.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside a Fragment you can [use `getFragmentManager()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager%28%29).

Comment: I am using support library for fragment so I have to call getSupportFragmentManager()

Comment: you can use it (the same method) in both cases. The fragment class in the support package has the getFragmentManager method. Please check the documentation that CommonsWare linked

Comment: +1 Nice . then what is the difference between them ?

Comment: and it is saying "getFragmentManager" is not available in support lib

Comment: it returns an instance of `v4.app.FragmentManager` instead of `app.FragmentManager`

Comment: Yes It is not giving in suggestion as well. It is telling getFragmentManager is in API level 11

Comment: then you are importing the native Fragment

Comment: Yes right. thanks :) I can accept answer in 4 minutes.